# Selectively deleting a site from history fully on Opera/Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, privacy, history, opera

When I attempt to selectively delete a site from the Opera site history, although it disappears from the history list it still appears with the suggestions feature in the address bar (obtained from history) and remains present in history files.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Visit a web site in Opera not visited before.  e.g. www.guardian.com.  Afterwards, close the tab.
2) In the Opera history, click "X Remove from history" next to the site.  It is removed from the list (as expected).
3) In the address bar, start typing the name of the site.  The suggestions still show the site as being listed in the history - even though it has supposedly been deleted.
4) In the Opera folder, when examining the contents of the History and History Provider Cache in Notepad, both files still contain the site - even though it has supposedly been deleted.

Using Opera 37.0.2178.43 on Windows 7 Pro desktop.  I've also experienced the same issue on Chrome (but not Firefox), and has been reproduced on more than one PC.  I don't use any syncing or accounts and PCs are virus/malware free.

Although not a show stopper, this can be quite an annoyance and a potential privacy concern, as the user thinks a site has been deleted from the history but it really hasn't.

Is this a bug?  Or can this behaviour be explained?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of overcoming this issue. After clearing the history, you need to remove those sites from predictions as well.

1. Disable prediction here(This applies to whole browser): [image: Option 1]
2. Delete those entries from dropdown menu: [image: Option 2]

Hope it helps!